# jQuery: iPhone Problems

Tags: jquery, iphone

I'm writing a website for iPhone and I use jQuery for image resizing and to scroll to the top.

Both are working in the Firefox on Mac but not on the iPhone. I don't know why because it's the same document and jQuery should be cross plattform...

Any guesses?

Best regards, Sebastian

**EDIT:**

This is my Code:

```
var width_max = $('#stiMobiContent').width();

$('img').resize({maxWidth: width_max})

$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

It although works in Safari on my Mac.

Comment: Well gee, I looked at your code and the problem is clearly...

Comment: Do the sites work in any browsers (safari???) on the Mac other then Firefox? It could be you have a bug that Firefox is ignoring but Safari isn't. I agree with @ceejayoz that without code or some significantly more substantial details then you gave us my guess would be gremlins.

Answer (score 0):

So I thought up a solution that might work:

```
$('a[href=#top]').click(function(event){
  $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then for your image just change the css to this:

```
img {width:100%; height:auto;}
```

That'll will make sure it's always the full width of it's container and the height will automatically match the right aspect ratio.

---

Additionally, I'd like to add that I think the `resize` method is only called when the `window` is resized. It's not clear in the documentation though.

Also most browsers have different ideas about how the browser window resize event should be addressed, as they all act a little different. Browser compatibility for `max-width` seems pretty shaky too.

Comment: Resize is part of this plugin: http://ditio.net/2010/01/02/jquery-image-resize-plugin/

I'll try those snippts tomorrow but now I'm to tired.

Comment: Ok, I tried your stuff today. The scrolling does not work. I think their are some problems with iPhone and jQuery because I although had problems with other features. For example, live() didn't work to and I tried a simple $('a').live('click', function() { alert('test'); }); so their is no chance that it was a problem with my code. Took me a long time to come around this :-/ However, the img resizing works perfect. The bad thing is that it scales all images but I used a wrapper so that only to large images are effected.